# Adding tables to SQLite database using Slick and Scala

Tags: database, sqlite, scala, slick

So I have SQLite database using Slick and I want to add and remove tables from it.
Here is what I have now:

Here is the database element class:

```
class Data(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[(Int, String)](tag, "myDB") {
  // This is the primary key column:
  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("NAME")
  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * : ProvenShape[(Int, String)] = (id, name)
}
```

I need to be able to create multiple tables using the class above. Something like this:

```
def addTable(name:String){
  db withSession { implicit session =>
    val newTable = TableQuery[Data]
    newTable.ddl.create
  }
}
```

Problem is that I cant create new table because one already exists with name "myDB". I tried to add a parameter for the name of the Table in the class Data like so:

```
class Data(tag: Tag,tableName:String)
```

But then I couldn't create a table at all and got an error

```
unspecified value parameter tableName
```

And how can I query a specific table from the database given the table name?
I tried to Implement this using Map with table name pointing to a table, but it doesnt work because the Map is not saved anywhere and is reset everytime the program starts.

This is what I had for querying a table:

```
def getDataFromTable(tableName:String)
{
  var res = ""
  db withSession { implicit session =>
    tables(tableName) foreach{
      case (id,name)=>
        res += id + " " + name + " "
    }
  }
  res
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition

```
class Data(tag: Tag, tableName: String)
  extends Table[(Int, String)](tag, tableName){

...
```

Usage

```
(new TableQuery(Data(_,"table_1"))).ddl.create
(new TableQuery(Data(_,"table_2"))).ddl.create
...
```